# Como imprimir mês atual usando lista com Python

Tags: python, datetime

Bom dia a todos, sou iniciante em Python e vi um tutorial sobre datas. Gostaria de saber se é possível imprimir o mês atual do ano utilizando uma lista, da mesma forma que foi possível imprimir o dia atual da semana. Segue código abaixo.

```
import datetime
from datetime import date

today = date.today()
wd = date.weekday(today)

days = ['Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado', 'Domingo']
months = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']

year = str(datetime.datetime.now().year)
month = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%B'))
day = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%d'))

print(f'{days[wd]}, {day} de {month} de {year}')
```

Desde já agradeço...

Comment: Em vez de ficar chamando `now` toda hora, poderia guardar em uma variável, algo como `hoje = datetime.datetime.now()` e depois bastaria fazer `hoje.year`, etc. Se bem que, para formatar, não precisa pegar bastaria fazer direto `strftime('%d de %B de %Y')`, por exemplo (e usando também a solução do primeiro link indicado acima, caso queira os nomes em português)

Answer (score 0):

Tens várias formas de conseguir isto, e diria que não precisas de tranformar nada em string (`strftime`):

Uma das formas:

```
from datetime import datetime

today = datetime.today()
days = ['Segunda-feira', 'Terça-feira', 'Quarta-feira', 'Quinta-feira', 'Sexta-feira', 'Sábado', 'Domingo']
months = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']

str_month = months[today.month-1] # obtemos o numero do mês e subtraímos 1 para que haja a correspondência correta com a nossa lista de meses  
str_weekday = days[today.weekday()] # obtemos o numero do dia da semana, neste caso o numero 0 é segunda feira e coincide com os indexes da nossa lista

print(f'{str_weekday}, {today.day} de {str_month} de {today.year}') # Quinta-feira, 11 de Agosto de 2022
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://ideone.com/TNVWe3)

Comment: Muito obrigado meu amigo, era exatamente isso que eu queria e acabei aprendendo um pouco mais com você.

Comment: De nada @BrunoBernardes, ainda bem que ajudei